# That's what we say

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Try make sense of this puzzle.

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This puzzle makes perfect sense if

> you read diagonally up and leftward.

Then you find

> sequences of letters that look like parts of English words. The words wrap around diagonally until they reach the leftmost column.

The right-most column is blank and

> missing the first letter of each word. Some of them only have one option to make a word. Some of them have a couple options. If you start with the sure things you start to see the vague shape of a message appearing.

If you fill them all in

> and then read upward you find
>  [image]
>  MERRY CHRISTMAS!

which is what we say.